# Define action when AlertDialog is dismissed by clicking outside

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

I'm making a simple TODO app in Flutter. Next to each item I have an "Edit" icon which opens an `AlertDialog` with pre-filled description and amount of that item. When I click outside of the dialog, it is dismissed, as expected. For this form I use two String variables called `description` and `amount`, as well as two controllers called `descriptionController` and `amountController`.

I also have the "Add" button, which opens a similar alert dialog with a similar form, in which I use same string variables and controllers.

The problem arises in the following scenario:
- I click the "Edit" button for a certain item. The dialog appears with pre-filled fields.
- I dismiss the dialog by clicking outside.
- I click the "New" button. The dialog appears, but instead of empty fields, I still see the values from the item that I was editing before.

One of the solutions would of course be to use separate controllers. But I would like to know if there is a possibility to detect that the dialog is dismissed by clicking outside and to perform a certain action (clear the controllers).

Thanks.

Comment: you are able to do so, solution is found here.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26542

Comment: Not the best solution, but you can try this - 
What you can do is, when you dismiss the Edit Dialog just store the values in the text variables and after that just set the descriptionController.text="",  or just use an onChanged Method in textfield and keep assigning the value to the text variables, and while dismissing set the descriptionController.text="".

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful in many cases.
Instead of detecting touch/click on barrier/outside AlertDialog, simply do the followings-

- Extract the `AlertDialog` widget and make it a `StatefulWidget`.
- A `StatefulWidget` always calls `deactivate()` and `dispose()` sequentially when it ends/pops. So you can do any specific actions inside any of these functions (based on your need) that you wanna do when the `AlertDialog` is dismissed.
- It will help you when the `AlertDialog` is dismissed using Android back button or click on Barrier/outside. **You might need to take extra precautions for any buttons used on the `AlertDialog` itself** i.e. detecting that button-click separately and thus avoiding any actions that you wanna do only when Android back button or click on Barrier/outside is used to dismiss the `AlertDialog`.

For example, say you are using a `TextButton` on `AlertDialog`.

```
TextButton(
      child: const Text(
        'Continue',
        softWrap: true,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          isContinueButtonPressed = true;
        });
        Navigator.of(context)
            .popAndPushNamed(SomeScreen.routeName);
      },
    )
```

Then inside the `deactivate()` and/or `dispose()`, do something like this-

```
@override
void deactivate() {
 if (!isContinueButtonPressed){
   // do your actions if 'continue' button on AlertDialog is not pressed
 } 
 super.deactivate();
}

@override
void dispose() {
 if (!isContinueButtonPressed){
   // do your actions if 'continue' button on AlertDialog is not pressed
 } 
 super.dispose();
}
```